# Why I've lost a Java rule configuration when upgrading from SQ 4.5.1 to 4.5.4?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I am facing this issue when I move from SonarQube version 4.5.1 to SonarQube version 4.5.4

In my 4.5.1 I had a custom change in rule squid:MethodCyclomaticComplexity. I changed the default complexity from 10 to 12.
Now when I try the same Java profile in 4.5.4 I get the default value of complexity again 10 instead of 12.

Here is the steps I followed.

1. Downloaded a fresh copy of SonarQube4.5.4.zip
2. Started the server
3. Restored the Quality profile [the back up was generated from my old
           4.5.1] using 'Restore Profile' option.
4. Set this profile as my default one
5. Executed the maven commands.

It shows the default value 10 for squid:MethodCyclomaticComplexity.

[By the way I can see the default value in my quality profile file which is generated from 4.5.1 is 12]

Please suggest

Comment: I use the default h2 database in this environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was due to the plugin change. During the SonarQube 4.5.4 installation I installed new Java plugin 3.3 . Some of the customized rules in quality profile generated from SonarQube 4.5.1 [which had old Java plugin] were not working good on SonarQube4.5.4 because of the updated Java plugin.